# angularFireCollection is not returning any data

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I have no issues when using implicit updates (angelFire).  However I need for some of my data use explicit updating.  So I implemented `angelFireCollection` on the exact same ref I was using previously but despite the console.log explicitly saying that the read was granted and trying it with both with the `onloadcallback` and without, I don't get data directly into my assigned variable AND once the callback fires I get a strange looking object that DOES contain the data but not in the form I expect.  My scope variable ends up with an empty collection.  Never gets populated.  Here is the code:

```
    var streamController = function ($rootScope, $scope, $log, $location, angularFireCollection,  profileService) {
    //Wait for firebaseLogin...
    $rootScope.$watch('firebaseAuth', init);      

    function init() {
        if ($rootScope.firebaseAuth == false) {
            return
        };       
        var refUsers = new Firebase($rootScope.FBURL+'/users/'+$rootScope.uid);
        $scope.profile = angularFireCollection(refUsers, function onload(snapshot) {
            console.log(snapshot)                
        });

     };
  };

  myApp.gwWebApp.controller('StreamController', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$log', '$location', 'angularFireCollection', 'profileService',
    streamController]);
```

}());

Here is what the console.log looks like ( ie; what snapshot looks like ):

```
>snapshot
T {z: R, bc: J, V: function, val: function, xd: function…}
```

Here is the earlier message before the snapshot was returned:

```
Firebase Login Succeeded! fbLoginController.js:16
FIREBASE: Attempt to read /users/529ccc5d1946a93656320b0a with auth={"username":"xxxxxxx@me.com","id":"529ccc5d1946a93656320b0a"} firebase.js:76
FIREBASE:   /: "auth.username == 'admin'" firebase.js:76
FIREBASE:       => false firebase.js:76
FIREBASE:   /users firebase.js:76
FIREBASE:   /users/529ccc5d1946a93656320b0a: "auth.id == $user" firebase.js:76
FIREBASE:       => true firebase.js:76
FIREBASE: 
FIREBASE: Read was allowed.
```

and finally the desired binding that ends up with an empty array:  again from the console:

> $scope.profile
>   []

Anyone know what I could possibly be doing wrong?? This is like 5 lines of code.  Frustrating.

I have put stops in `angelFireCollection` factory function and can see that the data is getting added to the collection in the callbacks inside that function but my binded variable never gets updated.

UPDATE
Ok experimenting with a plnkr.  It seems that `angularFireCollection` EXPECTS your returning a LIST of items.  The snapshot returns properly if you inspect `snapshot.val()` it will be whatever object structure was stored in firebase.  IF you use `angularFireCollection` it does indeed bind to the variable HOWEVER it turns a non-list object into a garbled mess and you can not access the object user the normal dot operator.  This is either a bug or it is a severe limitation of `angularFireCollection` which will cause me to revaluate how easily I can use firebase as the backend.  I can't share my plnkr because it is accessing non-public data but tomorrow if i have time I will create a public firebase with an object store and demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

Ok.  So it appears that indeed angularFireCollection is MEANT to be array based.  Which is fine.  It would be VERY helpful if the angularFire documentation was updated to make that clear.  As such it is not an implicit vs explicit update technique.

For an explicit non-array based approach I have come up with the following code.  Had I not been mislead by the documentation I would have gone down this path originally.

```
var MainCtrl = function($scope, angularFire) {
   $scope.test = {};
   var _url = 'https://golfwire.firebaseio.com/tmp';
   var _ref = new Firebase(_url);
   var promise = angularFire(_ref, $scope, 'implicit');
   promise.then ( function(data){
      $scope.explicit=angular.copy($scope.implicit );
   }); 
}
```

You then work locally with the 'explicit' copy and when ready just update the 'implicit' by assigning: $scope.implicit = $scope.explicit.

Here is a plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/bLJrL1

Comment: You may want to keep an eye on v2. http://angularfire.com/documentationv2.html It is currently in the rc stages but, it feels more transparent. It always returns objects and has an orderByPriority filter built in to make arrays for things like ng-repeat.